# How to read a labyrinth from a txt file and put it into 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, maze

I just started a small project which reads a txt file like this:

```
4
XSXX
X  X
XX X
XXFX
```

So my question is how to read this and put the labyrinth to 2D char array in C++. I tried to use 'getline' but I just make my code more complex. Do you know if there is an easy way to solve this problem ?

```
char temp;
    string line;
    int counter = 0;
    bool isOpened=false;
    int size=0;

    ifstream input(inputFile);//can read any file any name
    // i will get it from user

    if(input.is_open()){

    if(!isOpened){
        getline(input, line);//iterater over every line
        size= atoi(line.c_str());//atoi: char to integer method.this is to generate the size of the matrix from the first line           
    }
    isOpened = true;
    char arr2[size][size];       

    while (getline(input, line))//while there are lines
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {

            arr2[counter][i]=line[i];//decides which character is declared

        }
        counter++;
    }
```

Comment: Show what you have written and explain how it is deficient.

Comment: Don't ask to _"gimme teh codez plz"_, show what you've done and why it didn't work for you first please.

Comment: I just edited my question..

Comment: Is the number `4` giving you the number of characters in all the next lines?

Comment: It is the size of my labyrinth, like 4x4.

Comment: What is it about your code that doesn't work?

Comment: The problem is size. Compiler says it should be constant but I should get it from text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is due to the fact that you are trying to declare an array with a size that is a *non-constant expression*.

In your case `size` representing the number of elements in the array, must be a [constant expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression), since arrays are blocks of static memory whose size must be determined at compile time, before the program runs.

To solve it you could either leave the array with empty brackets and the size will be automatically deduced by the number of elements you place in it or 
you could use `std::string` and `std::vector` and then to read the `.txt` file you could write something like:

```
// open the input file
ifstream input(inputFile);

// check if stream successfully attached
if (!input) cerr << "Can't open input file\n";

string line;
int size = 0;     

// read first line
getline(input, line);

stringstream ss(line);
ss >> size;

vector<string> labyrinth;

// reserve capacity
labyrinth.reserve(size);

// read file line by line 
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {

    // read a line
    getline(input, line);

    // store in the vector
    labyrinth.push_back(line);
}

// check if every character is S or F

// traverse all the lines 
for (size_t i = 0; i < labyrinth.size(); ++i) {

    // traverse each character of every line
    for (size_t j = 0; j < labyrinth[i].size(); ++j) {

         // check if F or S
         if (labyrinth[i][j] == 'F' || labyrinth[i][j] == 'S') {

             // labyrinth[i][j]  is F or S
         }

         if (labyrinth[i][j] != 'F' || labyrinth[i][j] != 'S') {

             // at least one char is not F or S
         }
    }
}
```

As you can see this [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) is already "a kind of" 2D `char` array only with a lot of additionally provided facilities that allow a lot of operations on its content.

Comment: So how can I get every character to check if it is 'S' or 'F'? Or is there any way to put this vector to 2D char array ?

Comment: It worked for me. But I changed getline(input,getSize), because compiler gave me an error. So I used stoi to change int.